# What happens to a lambda that appears to delete itself while it's running?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I want to confirm that the following code has undefined behaviour.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    void bar()
    {
        auto callback = []() {
            std::cout << 42 << '\n';
        };

        foo = [this, callback]() {
            // Object holding the bound lambda is destroyed
            foo = nullptr;

            // Captured function invoked
            callback();
        };
    }

    std::function<void()> foo;
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.bar();
    t.foo();
}
```

Code of this form is crashing for me periodically. Maybe.

Originally, its form was more like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
    void bar()
    {
        foo = [=]() {
            // Object holding the bound lambda is destroyed
            foo = nullptr;

            // Function invoked through captured `this` ptr
            baz();
        };
    }

    void baz()
    {
        // Member data used
        std::cout << x << '\n';
    }

    std::function<void()> foo;
    int x = 42;
};

int main()
{
    T t;
    t.bar();
    t.foo();
}
```

…and in that condition I didn't experience any problems. I'm thinking that the captured `this` was more easily cached inside the lambda, such that the lambda's destruction did not practically break the subsequent calls. Whereas now that I'm using captured data, destruction of that captured data is more likely to exhibit UB-related problems.

Is this a reasonable interpretation? *Or* is execution of the lambda safe for the duration of the call, no matter what happens to the container holding it?

*I'm writing C++11 for GCC 4.8 on CentOS 6 and 7.*

Comment: Did you try some other compiler (a recent Clang or GCC), did you enable warnings, did you use some sanitizer? I'm guessing you do have UB, but I don't know well enough the standard to be sure

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: The problem is so intermittent that I don't trust any such experiments. e.g. whatever Coliru's running doesn't balk on this toy code at all (but then that could be simply because everything here is pretty easy to optimise)

Comment: You are not destroying the lambda because you capture its value not its reference use `&` symbol for capturing all the variables by reference in the lambda declaration.

Comment: @Mohit: But its value is the thing I'm invoking. Is that value not lost when the lambda "instance" is destroyed by `foo = nullptr`? The captured `callback` is basically just a [now non-existent] member variable of the closure type, no?

Comment: @Mohit - You are focusing on the wrong lambda here. It's about the second one that is destroyed prematurely.

Comment: Hmm could be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31493761/560648

Comment: If I recall correctly, lambda captures are fully implemented in gcc 4.9+. Plus the gcc flavour you're using is probably redhad patched.

Comment: Slightly modified code: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/12da0e740cbd90cf Couldn't find anything in the standard though.

Comment: @YSC: It certainly wouldn't be [the first time GCC 4.8's experimental C++11 support has bitten me on the bum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49498985/560648), but I think this one is probably my fault.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I think it is a dupe of that one as well. Particularly given Barry's answer. I too think it's just a more elaborate from of `delete this`, with the same considerations applying.

Comment: @tkausl: Thanks, that's helpful (slightly modified again: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83ab53c576b6fcc4) - I believe that confirms my suspicions

Comment: @StoryTeller: Okay agreed. Thanks all!

Comment: @StoryTeller `delete this`  Ahh ... the best thing to put in a constructor ever :)  saves doing `delete new Thing()`   ... ok - I'm going back into my hole now.